# TFS 2010: Rolling CI Builds

Tags: tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration

I've been looking around online at ways of improving our build time (which is currently ~30-40 minutes, depending on which build agent gets the task), and one common theme I've seen is use CI builds.

I understand the logic behind this, and it makes sense that it would reduce the time each build takes. Our problem, however, is that building on every check-in is a pointless use of our resources, because in our development branch, we only keep the latest successful build. This means that if 2 people check-in in a short space of time, whoever checked-in last will be the one whose build is kept.

It's this reason (along with disk space limitations) that we changed to using Rolling Builds, so that we only built the development branch a maximum of once every 45 minutes (obviously we could manually trigger builds on otp of that).

What I want to know (and haven't been able to find anywhere) is whether there's a way of combining rolling builds AND continuous integration. So keep building only once every 45 minutes, but only get and build files that have changed.

I'm not even sure it's possible, and if not then I'll look into other ways, but this seems like something that should be possible.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to keep the builds during the day? How often are you deploying them to somewhere?

Comment: No particular reason, other than knowing fairly quickly when someone has broken the build. We do deploy to test servers fairly regularly, however, so it's mainly for that.

Comment: Ah I see, you want to keep the history so you can track who broke the build? Could you retain the last 10 failed builds, but only the latest successful build?

Comment: I'm happy to change it back to CI builds only, rather than the combination, but as mentioned above (albeit briefly), the disk space is another issue here as TFS doesn't seem to delete the files in the drop folder.

Comment: You can configure your CI build definition not to output to a drop folder.